# What is "social networking"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[What is a succinct definition of social networking?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-succinct-definition-of-social-networking?redirected_qid=20816499)

It seemes it always refers to Internet.
Is "hanging out with friends" a kind of social networking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be. I like the following definition of social networking:

> Social networking is the practice of expanding the number of one's business and/or social contacts by making connections through individuals, often through social media sites such as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google+. [(WhatIs.com))](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/social-networking)

This definition recognises the importance of social media, but acknowledges that it is not the sole method of social networking. Many professional organisations hold social events specifically to encourage networking among their members. Most service clubs, e.g. Lions Club, Rotary, Freemasons, Probus, etc., provide opportunities for social networking in addition to their primary service functions.